# Quadrangulations where each vertex has an even degree

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am trying to find a planar quadrangulation or show that there does not exist one where all vertices have an even degree. Note that I am particularly looking at cases where we have $n\ge10$ vertices - obviously we could take a $C_4$ graph (a cycle on $4$ vertices), and this would automatically hold, but I am struggling to come up with any other cases of this. I was thinking of a "chain" of $C_4$'s such that we have $k$ copies of $C_4$ that are joined only by one vertex with one another. This construction has an even degree for every vertex, however, it is not a quadrangulation due to the outer face having more than $4$ vertices on its boundary. Maybe one could somehow derive a construction from this idea? Or perhaps construct a proof to say that no such quadrangulation exists - this may follow from the fact that when trying to draw said quadrangulations, I keep getting vertices of an odd degree, and it feels like this is forced to happen in a recursive manner. However, I am not exactly sure whether this is true either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many exist.

For example, consider the following graph:
Let $a_i$, $i\leq 8$ be a set of $8$ vertices, and $b_j$, $j\leq 2$ be a set of $2$ vertices. Make every vertex $a_i$ adjacent to every vertex $b_j$.

The $a_i$ vertices have degree $2$, and the $b_j$ vertices have degree $8$.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a picture?

Comment: I don't see how this is a quadrangulation; whenever I draw this, I keep getting triangular areas in my drawing.

Comment: I added a picture @causalityrefilm. You can see it shouldn't have triangles since it's bipartite.

Comment: Ah I see, this clears it right up. Thank you so much. It's not necessary, but I would also love to see more non-bipartite examples if you can come up with any. Thanks!!

Comment: @causalityrefilm. All planar quadrangulations are bipartite. If a planar graph has any odd cycles, it also has a face bounded by an odd number of edges.

Comment: I see, I think I get it now.